# Rspec tests failing if run all together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, integration-testing

I've 2 _spec files: the first containing unit test, the other one some integration tests.

While running them by specifying file name they are alle green, while running them as "rspec" 3 of them are failing.

I'm using database_cleaner gem to clean test db around each test.

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

I'm using "let" to instantiate objects and FactoryGirl to create sample objects.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Comment: This sounds to me like the database is not being reset correctly between tests - you can probably verify this is the case given what the exact failures are (ie if you are checking collection size and there are superfluous elements).


It could also be legitimate conflicts between the tests - it depends what the failures are, and if the failures are order dependent.

Comment: @oowowaee I've fixed by moving from def to let to instantiate objects. Now is working as expected and the same goes for DatabaseCleaner

Answer (score 1):

Some issues could be:

- Class variables that you are modifying and not resetting between tests. Class variables are anti-patterns and should generally be avoided.
- You aren't properly stubbing things like constants.

Anything that maintains a state between tests can cause the issue you are seeing. Use your debugger to check the state of objects during each test.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by moving from def to let. Be aware of defines